# Merge objects within Entity Framework?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm attempting to create a merge function, in my application i have a users object that has PK/FK relationship to other objects relating to that user. (for my example say Contact is the object, and Orders have a 1:Many relationship to Contacts.

The function would pass in two EF objects, with one being the "kept" record and the other being "merged". Whereby all data in the kept should win should there be duplicate field entry. This is all easy enough, but i can't understand how to point all the link objects to the new record PK/FK issue.

How can this be achieved within EF(Design first)?

Example code from MS - Can i simply load the objects related to the merge and change their FK relationship? (differentcontact in example below). Such that say a Contact was created twice, and orders exist under both Contacts, we want to keep the first Contact, and remove the duplicate one. First we must re-assign all the orders to the correct contact (differentcontact), and then would be able to remove the duplicate contact value?

```
 Using context As New POCOAdventureWorksEntities()
    Dim orderId As Integer = 43659
    Dim differentContactID As Integer = 5
    Dim order As Order = context.Orders.Include("Contact").Where(Function(o) o.SalesOrderID = orderId).First()
    Dim differentContact As Contact = context.Contacts.First(Function(c) c.ContactID = differentContactID)

    order.ContactID = differentContact.ContactID '// Something like this? 
    context.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: What you have looks OK - are you running into a problem?  You could probably (I'm only familiar with Code First) also do `order.Contact = differentContact` and let EF handle the keys.  If you are updating all the orders for a contact, you could also look at [`EntityFramework.Extended`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) which supports bulk updates without loading the entities (not used it, but it looks interesting).

Comment: Some tables have the FK / PK mapped, such that i could do order.contactID = NewContact; some do not, such that would something like order.contact.contactID = NewContact